# why (=) is automatically removed from url(Query String) in angular 8

Tags: angular

I Define Route Like This:-

```
path: 'reset-password/:mail/:token',
component: ConfirmResetPasswordComponent
```

In that route ***mail*** and ***token*** is now dynamic.

Now the dynamic URL is like
***https://domain_name/reset-password/xyz@yopmail.com/tyuiokjtyuiiurtyuiasdfjk=***

Then why the (=) is automatically disappeared from the URL (*see at very last of the URL) when its dynamic value is load. I want to keep = within the URL when it comes.

Comment: Is this base64? If so, you should use the URL-safe (base64url) variant, as `=` is a reserved character; or you need to escape it (percent encode).

Comment: `=` (and `@`) are reserved keywords in the [URI RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2). How are you passing the URL?

Comment: URL is generated from the Backend, and (=) is the part of the token.

Comment: Then your back-end is generating invalid URLs.

Comment: the token is the hashed value.

Comment: I want to keep that hashed value and return it to the backend as it is.